# How was Seven of Nine the seventh of nine people to be assimilated?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, borg, seven-of-nine

As a girl, Annika Hansen was assimilated into the Collective, along with her parents, and named Seven of Nine. Who were the other six people who were assimilated along with them?

Comment: Incidentally, I assume that her name was simply the last two fields in her Borg IP address: 15.10.228.9.7, or something like that.

Comment: @Joe, you're sure the Borg wouldn't want to use IPv6?

Comment: I have to admit I've always thought of her, in that outfit, as Two of Thirty-Eight...

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Seven of Nine was not assimilated with nine other people. She was assimilated along with her parents, Magnus and Erin Hansen.

At some point in the future, she was then assigned to a working group servicing [Unimatrix 01](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unimatrix_01). This group contained nine drones, of which she was the seventh, hence her full Borg name

> "***Seven of Nine, Tertiary Adjunct of Unimatrix 01***"

We see several other members of this group ([2 of 9](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Two_of_Nine), [3 of 9](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Three_of_Nine) and [4 of 9](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Four_of_Nine)) in the Voyager episode 'Survival Instinct'.

Answer (score 26):

## She wasn't!

Your question rests on a faulty premise.  It is incorrect to assume that a designation refers to the number of individuals assimilated at the time.  Rather, [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Borg) explains that:

> A drone's designation typically **described its position within a group**, e.g. "Third of Five."

So, there *need not have been nine people present at the time of Seven's assimilation!*  'Seven of Nine' merely refers to her position in a specific group.

Additionally, as pointed out by @O. R. Mapper in the comments below, in 'The Omega Directive' (*VOY*), Harry is reassigned by Seven to the designation of 'Two of Ten'.  The fact that she reassigns him provides strong evidence to indicate that the designation refers to a position within a group (which can change) rather than a 'name' which it would not make sense to change!

Comment: Hmm, I read in a novel that that was the way they were named... Guess it was wrong.

Comment: To add to this answer, we see a few others from her group in the episode Survival Instinct. One of them seems to be bejoran, so it's clear they were not assimilated at the same time.

Comment: To add even more to this answer, in [*The Omega Directive* (VOY 4x18)](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/418.htm), Seven of Nine leads the team examinating the titular Omega particle. At one point, she tells Harry: "I'm reassigning you to chamber maintenance. Your new designation is Two of Ten." This underlines that Borg designations have nothing to do with their original assimilation, but are rather dynamically assigned within organisational units.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper That episode bugged me, because the conversation between Harry and Seven implied that smaller numbers had lower rank...

Comment: @Michael: I thought so, too, at first, but upon reading the transcript I linked to again, I think the *demotion* he is referring to is based upon his reassignment to the chamber maintenance crew (among which he happens to be 2 of (equally-ranked) 10), not the number itself. (Or even if that wasn't the meaning intended by the writer, the dialogue is vague enough to let us interpret it like this, which IMHO seems more fitting.)

Comment: Hmm, as I think about this now, if being reassigned to chamber maintenance changed Harry's designation to 2 of 10, there must have been 9 drones assigned to chamber maintenance before that moment. In which case, wouldn't it have been more efficient to designate Harry as 10 of 10? By making him #2, at least one other drone's first number must also change (in addition to all of their second numbers changing from 9 to 10).

Comment: @DanHenderson - My understanding is that she was integrating Starfleet protocols (promotion and demotion) with Borg protocols. It also has to be said that she has almost certainly regained sufficient humanity by this point to want to mess with Harry Kim to punish him for questioning her orders.

Comment: @DanHenderson It makes sense to start with the basics, so the higher numbers must do more advanced stuff. If there was a group of 10 assigned to that task, maybe there currently was only one.

Comment: Well, I took a look at the transcript that @O.R.Mapper provided and I realize that the "10" does not appear to be tied to Chamber Maintenance, as Crewman Dell's designation was changed to 3 of 10 with his assignment change, and Harry's was changed from 6 of 10 to 2 of 10. So if the designation *didn't* relate to rank and/or duty assignment, then there'd be no reason to change it, as the change produces an (admittedly minor) cognitive cost to the crew members, but zero benefit, unless it *does* relate to one of those attributes.

Comment: @DanHenderson: You seem to be assuming all instances of *10* refer to the same group of 10. I do not consider that necessary; *2 of 10* might simply tell an individual drone how to behave in a group of 10 (e.g. what communication channel/internal ID to use: number 2).

Answer (score 5):

Borg drone designations in the form *n of m* were established in the Next Generation episode Season 5 Episode 23 *"I Borg"*.

In that episode, the crew found a crashed Borg scout ship. On board of that ship were 5 borg drones of which only one was alive. The surviving drone identified itself as "three of five". The crew inferred that it meant that the drone was the 3rd member of a group of five drones.

Later Star Trek works kept using this naming system for Borg drones. "Seven of Nine" means that she was the 7th member of a group of nine drones.

An alternative explanation could be that the second number is the number of the unit the drone belongs to (7th drone of the 9th group of drones), but there is no canon example of a Borg drone where the first number is larger than the 2nd, so there is no reason to believe that the hypothesis from *"I Borg"* was incorrect.

There are, however, three examples of Borg which are not named with the *n of m* naming system:

- "Locutus of Borg", the name assigned to Captain Picard after being assimilated
- The "Borg Queen" (although she might not technically count as a drone)
- "One", the 29th century technology Borg drone from the Voyager episode Season 5 Episode  2 *"Drone"* (But this designation was given to it by itself after inspiration from Neelix, not by the Borg collective to which it never had any contact)

So there is precedent for the Borg collective giving special names to drones which have a very unique purpose.

Comment: I think it's fair to say that the queen doesn't count as a drone. :)